# Display don't work after driver install

Tags: pi-3, display, driver

I bought a display via eBay (https://www.ebay.at/itm/3-5-TFT-LCD-Touch-Screen-Module-320-480-RGB-Display-Case-For-Raspberry-Pi/391223449334?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649) to get it to work for my Raspiblitz Pi. The display is already mounted and enlightens, but nothing is shown after installment of the drivers.

Maybe you can help me.

I did the following steps:

I got the drivers from here --> http://en.kedei.net/raspberry/raspberry.html

It's the LCD_show_v6_1_3

1.) So i ssh into the Raspiblitz
2.) Downloading the drivers with sudo wget "http://en.kedei.net/raspberry/v6_1/LCD_show_v6_1_3.tar.gz"
3.) Unpacking tar -xzvf LCD_show_v6_1_3.tar.gz

Following the other steps below. Everything finishes successfully and Pi is rebooting, but after reboot nothing is shown on the display.

Description for installation from the display manufacturer:

b. Using the drive.

```
Writing your own image files to the SD card, and start the Raspberry Pi

Ensure that the network connection is normal

The LCD screen and the Raspberry Pi board is properly connected

Copy the driver to raspberry pi (using ssh or use U disk medium mounted)

Unzip the file and start the installation.

First expansion sd card sudo raspi-config select expand_roofts then sudo reboot

Restart enter the following command:

Unzip the file tar -xzvf LCD_show_v6.tar.gz

Jumped into a folder cd LCD_show_v6

To upgrade the system update sudo apt-get update

Backup data sudo ./LCD_backup

Install the driver sudo ./LCD35_v

Wait for some time and the system will install the driver automatically restarts

If you want to re-use before installing the system, you can use sudo ./LCD_restore

Note: Before you update your system, you must use at the command sudo apt-mark hold raspberrypi-bootloader

Then use the following command,

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Otherwise it will fail in the future may restart

Answer (score 1):

Please download the latest version of the driver, I tried different versions, and finally only the latest official driver version works (http://kedei.net/raspberry/raspberry.html). I uploaded it to Droplr, you can download it from here: https://d.pr/f/kh5JbR

Comment: What do you mean with *version*?

Comment: @Ingo Hi, it seems Kedei keeps updating this driver package silently, as I've found different versions on the internet (but they are all in the same name), their sizes are dramatically different, and if I install an old version, my Raspberry Pi simply can't boot at all, only shows a blank screen.